# Add new columns based on values in other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, function, apply

I am struggling to convert the following line of code into r.

```py
for genre in c_a:
    df['is_'+str(genre)] = df['genre'].apply(lambda x: genre in [y.strip() for y in x.split(',')])
```

basically, I have a object (type "character", with 1341 values in it), and I'd like to add new columns of each value of the variable, and also asign 0/1 value to the new column by checking if the new column is included in the genre column.

For example:

Current Input:

| Genre |
| --- |
| dance pop, pop |
| country, pop |

Expected Output:

| Genre | dance pop | pop | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dance pop, pop | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| country, pop | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I am not familiar with apply and lambda function in R. I only know how to solve the problem through a for loop, which is slow.

Comment: Hi do you want help code in Python ? if not would recommend you to remove python from tag.

Comment: How does your input exactly look like?

Comment: @R. Baraiya Hi, I'd like to get help in R. Thank you for bringing that up.

Comment: @Martin Gal Hi, I have edited my question, so you can see the current input and expected output. Basically, right now I only have "Genre" column along with other features, and I want to modify this "Genre" by looking at its values.

Comment: Your input, is it a data.frame or a vector?

Comment: @Martin Gal, my input is a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Genre": ["Dance pop, pop", "country, pop"]})
for col in set(sum([i.split(',') for i in df['Genre']],[])):          ##['Dance pop', ' pop', 'country', ' pop']
    df[col] = df['Genre'].apply(lambda x: 1 if col in x.split(',') else 0)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `tidyverse` approach, but I doubt it would speed things up. Suppose your data is stored in a vector `genre`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

genre <- c("dance pop, pop", "country, pop")

genre %>% 
  data.frame(genre = .) %>% 
  expand_grid(genres = unique(trimws(unlist(strsplit(genre, ","))))) %>% 
  mutate(value = +str_detect(genre, genres)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = genres)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  genre          `dance pop`   pop country
  <chr>                <int> <int>   <int>
1 dance pop, pop           1     1       0
2 country, pop             0     1       1
```

- First we create a data.frame with a new `genres` column, that contains all unique genres extracted from the `genre` vector.
- Next we look for a match between the `genres` and the `genre` column, converting it into a binary value.
- Finally we bring it into a rectangular shape using `pivot_wider`.

If your data is stored in a data.frame a similar approach works:

```r
data.frame(genre = c("dance pop, pop", "country, pop")) %>% 
  expand_grid(genres = unique(trimws(unlist(strsplit(.$genre, ","))))) %>% 
  mutate(value = +str_detect(genre, genres)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = genres)
```

returning the same output.